# JSON.stringify output to display in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I POST my table data using ajax in database. Now I want to get back when I give click the open button.

```js
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/./Service/GetPageInfo",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({

                filename: filename
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                //var p = JSON.stringify('[' + data + ']');
               // alert(p.GetPageInfoResult[0])
                //var k = data.main[0];
                //alert(data.length);
                //var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + data + ']');
                //alert(JSON.parse(data));
                var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 2);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
```

When I give my file name I want to display my pageinfo. I get data like

```
[{"main":{"sub":[],"tittle":"oops","startvalue":"21","stopvalue":"45","status":"","accumalated":"","comment":""}}]
```

Comment: have a look at jquery datatables - it can accept json to create tables

Comment: but i only need that values seperatly means column1:oops; column2: 21....

Answer (score 0):

You have not cleared where you want place your resultant **Json**. Below is that  **Success** result placed in **div** having **table** . It is just a sample you may change as per your requirement:

```
  function OnSuccess(response) {
                 debugger;
                 var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                 var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                 var page = xml.find("Table");
                 var row = "";
                 $('#popupdiv tbody').html('');
                 page.each(function () {
                     var page = $(this);
                     row = " " + page.find("tittle").text() + " " + page.find("startvalue").text() +
                           " " + page.find("stopvalue").text() + " " + page.find("status").text() +
                           " " + page.find("accumalated").text() + " " + page.find("comment").text() + "";
                     $('#popupdiv tbody').append(row);
                 });
             }
```

Comment: my table id is datatable and colume id are column 1,colun2........column6.

Comment: i dont understand this line  var xml = $(xmlDoc);

Comment: The above code is written on the web page ,depending on your json result the field names in database must tittle,startvalue,etc. And var xml = $(xmlDoc);  is just a name of variable to which parseXML of your response is sent